# JavaScript translate depending on index

Tags: javascript

So I have a code like this

```
const letterPosition = () => {
    const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.txt li');
    letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        letter.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translateY((index * 10)vh)');
    });
}
letterPosition();
```

and it doesnt work... Any solutions? (i want to change each letter position depending on array index)

Comment: use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#:~:text=Template%20literals%20are%20string%20literals,editions%20of%20the%20ES2015%20specification.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not referencing the index variable correctly, your style attribute is always the same. Also the parenthesis in translateY are not necessary.
Depending on your runtime you can try template strings

```
letter.setAttribute('style', `transform:translateY(${index * 10}vh)`);
```

or string concatenation

```
letter.setAttribute('style', 'transform:translateY(' + (index * 10) + 'vh)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use template literals on you code to access the `index` variable and make sure that the element is displayed as block or inline-block to make the transform property works like this.

```js
const letterPosition = () => {
    const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.txt li');
    letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        letter.setAttribute('style', `transform:translateY(${index * 10}vh); display: inline-block;`);
    });
}
letterPosition();
```

```html
<ul class="txt">
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
  <li>Hey</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/960g1afk/

You need to use string literal:

```
    let css =  `transform:translateY(${index*5}vh)`
    letter.setAttribute('style',css);
```